# BigDecimal в ruby

Tags: математика, ruby, числа

Доброго времени суток.

Есть такой кейз что:

```
require 'bigdecimal/math'
include BigMath

num1 = BigDecimal.new(1) / BigDecimal.new(6);
num2= BigDecimal.new(1) / BigDecimal.new(600);
num3 = BigDecimal.new(1) / BigDecimal.new(600000);
num4 = BigDecimal.new(1) / BigDecimal.new(60000011);

printf(num1.to_s + "\n");
printf(num2.to_s + "\n");
printf(num3.to_s + "\n");
printf(num4.to_s + "\n");
```

получаются следующие результаты:

```
0.166666666666666667E0
0.1666666666666667E-2
0.1666666666667E-5
0.16666663611E-7
```

Вопрос: Как вы можете заметить, числа имеют разные количество знаков после запятой. Хотелось бы сделать так что при различных манипуляциях можно было зафиксировать число знаков после запятой.
То есть если поставить допустим, что мне нужно 32 знака после запятой, то во всех результатах будем иметь 32 знака. И второй вопрос почему он округляет их по-разному? (первом вывел 18 знаков, во втором 16, в третьем 13, в четвертом 11)

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: А какой класс у переменных num1...num4?

Comment: ну я так понимаю если я создаю BigDecimal то тип автоматически будет у переменной BigDecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для периодических дробей есть специальный класс [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Rational.html).

Comment: Rational работает на сколько я понял с целыми. Мне же нужен BigDecimal) операции сложения/вычетания/деления и тд.

Comment: то есть что если 1.353627373/2.36374748383